# slide down once click on a tag does not slide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have bunch of anchor tags that are created dynamically. I basically want to invoke a function and display content of that executed function just under that anchor tag using jquery slideDown. Every `<a>` tag with`id="id"` and every `<a>` tag has a `<div id="slidedown">`.

I am using jquery.slideto.min.js.

The below code does not even slide down at all.

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json'
        url: '/lists',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != null) {
                var html = '<ul>';
                $.each(data.apis, function (i, item) {
                    html += '<li class="res">';
                    html += '<div class="hed"><h2><a id="id" href="/api/' + item + '.json">' + item + '</a></h2></div><div id="slidedown"></div>';
                    html += '</li>';
                });
                html += '</ul>';
                $('#exDiv').empty();
                $('#exDiv').append(html);
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Error');
        },
        contentType: 'application/json'
    });

   $(document).on('click','#id', function(e) {

       e.preventDefault();
       var link = this.href;
       $('#slidedown').slideto();
    });
});
```

I see `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined` on my console once I click on any of the `<a>` tags.

Comment: It would help to see your HTML, but it sounds like you have several problems. The first is that the `#a` and `#slideown` elements will be duplicated which is invalid as `id` attributes must be unique within a document. Use a class instead. Secondly, you need to traverse the DOM from the reference of `this` to find the neighbouring `.slidedown` element and call `slideto()` on that.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan please check, updated

Comment: thanks - I added an answer for you

Comment: could you please console.log(data.apis); and let us see the result please ?

Comment: @AlaaM.Jaddou that has `[list1, list2, list3]`

Comment: yeah i know that has a list i need to see that list

Comment: yeah its basically lists list1, list2, list3 and then further code has a REST call that matches so for example, click on list1 should invoke api/list1 REST call that returns JSON.

Comment: **@fscore** what is version then ??? is that something from the rest returns ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that will solve the problem but `$('slidedown')` is not a valid selector, should be `$('#slidedown')` because you have `div` with identifier `slidedown` : `<div id="slidedown">`.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue you have is that you are generating duplicate `id` attributes, which is invalid. Change them to classes instead. Then you can traverse the DOM in the `click()` handler to find the related `.slidedown` element using `next()`. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json'
    url: '/lists',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data != null) {
            var html = '<ul>';
            $.each(data.apis, function (i, item) {
                html += '<li class="res">';
                html += '<div class="hed"><h2><a class="id" href="/api/' + item + '.json">' + item + '</a></h2></div><div class="slidedown"></div>';
                html += '</li>';
            });
            html += '</ul>';
            $('#exDiv').empty().append(html);
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('Error');
    },
    contentType: 'application/json'
});

$(document).on('click','.id', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var link = this.href; // you can remove this if it's not used.
   $(this).next('.slidedown').slideto();
});
```

Comment: I tried your code change above but still does not work